# Change showcase image source with jQuery only works in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, dom, cross-browser

I made the mistake of only testing my website in Chrome before putting it online, and am now quickly trying to patch some of the errors people using Firefox and IE are reporting.

On the buggy webpage, there's images with the class `block` scattered around, and an introductory default image with the id `currentImg` in the center. When the user clicks a block, the `currentImg` gets its `src` attribute changed to that of the selected block, showcasing a larger version of the clicked picture.

```
$('.block').click(function(){
    var id = this.id; //Gets clicked block id
    var src = ($(this).css('background-image')); //Gets block image source
    src = src.replace('url(','').replace(')',''); //Formats file path
    //alert(src); //Source check (Always successful)

    $('#currentImg').attr('src', src); //I think this is where the issue is
});
```

The showcased image never changes from the default. When I implement a fading transition, the default fades out and comes back, rather than a new image.

JSFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/Noff/rqpu3d5b/6/embedded/result/

Comment: More information need. A jsfiddle would be great. But, maybe there is something wrong with the image url. Is it absolute ? Or relative ? Print to us the url of the image that you're wanting to set.

Comment: Sorry, guys, I'll definitely start with a Fiddle next time. @JoãoMosmann The image urls are relative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that there is some inconsistency between different browsers in how browsers return the `background-image` property. The following are all valid `url` declaration.

1. `url(image.png)`
2. `url('image.png')`
3. `url("image.png")`

However, different browsers return the property differently, and it does not necessarily match how it is written in the CSS. In your case, it seems that Firefox is returning the `url` function with quotes, but Chrome is not. Your string replace to extract the URL does not expect them, so it ends up with quotes surrounding the URL.

To solve this, you need a more-robust string replace. The regex should solve you problem.

```
src = src.replace(/url\(["']?([^"']*)["']?\)/, "$1");
```

This regex will capture the image URL from withing the `url` declaration, handling the `'` or `"` characters if present.

Here is a breakdown of the parts of the regex.

```
    url\(              //Match url(
        ["']?          //Match either " or ' if present.
        ([^"']*)       //Match any characters except " and ' and save them in the $1 variable.
        ["']?          //Match either " or ' if present.
    \)                 //Match )
```

The final solution.

```
$('.block').click(function(){
    var id = this.id; //Gets clicked block id
    var src = ($(this).css('background-image')); //Gets block image source
    src = src.replace(/url\(["']?([^"']*)["']?\)/, "$1"); //Formats file path

    $('#currentImg').attr('src', src); //I think this is where the issue is
});
```

**NOTE:**

If you are using relative URL's in your `background-image` properties in an external CSS, keep in mind that the inline styles will be relative to the HTML document, rather than the CSS document.

Comment: +1 for the information about how the browsers return the property differently, but even with the correct relative urls showing up in the  alert(src), the images won't show, even though they seem to have the correct path.

Comment: @Nick Do you have a live example I can check out? If you set the `background-image` with a relative link from a CSS file in another directory, the relative path would be incorrect when made inline (and thus relative to the document, rather than CSS).

Comment: Oh gosh, I just set up the JSFiddle with absolute links to random images, which could be really misleading if that's the problem

Comment: @Nick There was a bug in my regex. See the updated answer for the fixed regex. Other than that, your fiddle looks to be working.

Comment: Thank you so much! I'll have to read over your awesome explanation of regex again in the morning.